# How to deploy a flex+java+blazeds application?

Tags: java, apache-flex, apache, tomcat, blazeds

i have a problem, I developed an application using flex+java+blazeds with tomcat that provide flex enviroment.

I want to deploy my application using tomcat but I can't, how can I deploy my app?

Comment: can you be more specific? Does the server you're using support servlets?

Answer (score 1):

This post can help you http://corlan.org/2008/06/05/creating-a-combined-flexjava-project-in-flex-builder-wo-lcdsblazeds/

Answer (score 0):

In project properties choose -> **Flex Build Path** -> set **output folder** to "**WebContent**" , **output folder URL** to url e.g **http://localhost:8080/yourappname** . This will allow Tomcat to automatically pick up the generated flex files from the WebContent directory.